# If I have a declaration with keywords in the header file, should I include the same keywords in the definition itself?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, albeit with a small amount of programming experience, and wanted to know if there is any global consensus on including keywords in the definition or not.

For example (not a valid statement, but for example):

```
class Dog : Animal {
    void foo() const override final foo bar ... keywords;
}
```

Is it generally recommended (for clarity's sake) to do the same in the definition, or should I just leave them off?

```
Dog::foo() const override final foo bar ... keywords {
    //
}
```

Are there any keywords that MUST be included in the definition if included in the declaration?

Comment: Depends on the keyword. If you omit `const` you aren't defining the same function you declared. Not to mention others aren't allowed in an out of class definition. [Please choose a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise that. Is that the only main exception? Will take a look at the book thread, but found that they were either too beginner or too advanced for me with my experience. :(

Comment: It is necessary for the definition to include enough information (class name, function name, return type, argument types, `const` qualifiers, exception specification, etc) so the definition matches the declaration.    Note that `final` is an identifier, not a keyword.  Beyond that, your question is unclear.

Comment: @Peter - An identifier? Are you sure you did not mistype?

Comment: @Peter Which, I guess, is where my question stems from: how much information in the definition is enough to match the function signature.

Comment: @TimothyRune - Rest assured, your compiler will tell you. There's no guesswork involved.

Comment: @StoryTeller That makes sense. Thanks! :)

Comment: @StoryTeller - no, I did not mistype.

Comment: @Peter - Then you seem to be intent on confusing the OP for the sake on pedantry. This is a ["specifier"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.mem#nt:virt-specifier) when used in the context the OP is using it.

Comment: @StoryTeller - Don't presume you can read or make accusations about my intent, simply because I respond to different aspects of a question than you do.

Comment: @Peter - It wasn't the aspect, but the content of  the response to said aspect. Let's be accurate. Your intent is immaterial if the content doesn't help towards achieving it.

Comment: Before you go getting on your high horse, StoryTeller, it might pay for YOU to check your comments for accuracy.   Using the same source you linked to, have a look at ["lex.name"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/lex.name), particularly para 2 and table 3, which explicitly state that `override` and `final` are "identifiers with special meaning".

Comment: @Peter - Good thing I checked back. Or I would never have had a chance to answer. I never claimed it wasn't a valid identifier, I claimed your comment would confuse the OP. Because in this context it's **not** an identifier, since it doesn't identify any entity.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the specific keyword.

As StoryTeller notes in the comments, `const` **is** part of the function signature. A declaration with `const` and a declaration without declare two distinct functions (and overload resolution will determine which declaration will be used for in a given expression). The same applies to `volatile`. Hence, you'll **must** also use it in the definition, so that declaration and definition can be matched.

`virtual` **must not** be used in the member definition, and the same applies to `override` and `final`. These keywords **do not** affect the function signature.

So, there's no need for consensus, since it's not subjective. There are two hard rules, and one reason for those two rules.